# Symmetric group action on sphere

Tags: general-topology

I often read that the symmetric group $\Sigma_n$ acts on the sphere $S^n$ by permuting coordinates. Can someone explicitely explain this action to me? How do I have to see the sphere (which base point)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can think of the sphere as the points in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ with distance 1 to the origin: $S^n=\{(x_0, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \ | \ \sum x_0^2=1\}$. Hence you can let act the symmetric group on these elements like that: $\sigma(x_0, x_1, \dots, x_n):= (x_0, x_{\sigma(1)}, \dots, x_{\sigma(n)})$. You can see this as fixing the poles.

Comment: This is very helpful! Thanks a lot. Now I see why it's permuting *coordinates*

Comment: Of course, you can actually have $\Sigma_{n+1}$ act on the sphere...

Comment: And you can have the signed symmetric group act on the sphere https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoctahedral_group...